# jQuery click event is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

this code is based on clicking an image that activate a radio button that is hidden.  to register an answer to the database,
however it's working fine on all browsers except internet explorer. any advice would be appropriated

```
    main : function(){
        var thisoptions = this.options;
        // Set up page:
        // Add grey borders
        $("input:radio").each (function () {
            var spanId = "imageBox_"+$(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+spanId).addClass('greyBorder');
         })
        // Pre-set already checked boxes with the highlight class
        $("input:radio:checked").each(function () {
            var spanId = "imageBox_"+$(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+spanId).removeClass('greyBorder');
            $("#"+spanId).addClass('imgChecked');
        })

        // Highlight image when clicked
        $(".imageBox_"+thisoptions.q_id).click(function(){
            $(".imageBox").removeClass('imgChecked');
            $(".imageBox").addClass('greyBorder');
            $(this).removeClass('greyBorder');
            $(this).addClass('imgChecked');
        });

        // Highlight image when textbox used
        $("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
            var spanId = "imageBox_"+ $(this).attr('data-for');
            $(".imageBox").removeClass('imgChecked');
            $(".imageBox").addClass('greyBorder');
            $("#"+spanId).removeClass('greyBorder');            
            $("#"+spanId).addClass('imgChecked');
        });
    }
  };
```

in internet explorer when I press the image all border colour changes and everything looks like it's been checked but the hidden radio button is not checked. even tho it works fine in all other browsers !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the event handler to this:

```
$('body').on('click','your image selector',function(){
your code goes here...
});
```

Comment: And why exactly...?

Comment: It's like IE doesn't recognize the image, kinda interprets it as it hasn't been loaded with the DOM, so by executing the code above, you attach the event listener to the body instead of the element directly :)

Comment: _"in internet explorer **when I press the image all border colour changes**"_

Comment: that's the default focus action, but the jquery event hasn't been executed, no? injecting an alert inside the function will probably won't execute either

Comment: @DireWolf I guess there is something wrong with the selector try:
`$('body').on('click',".imageBox_"+thisoptions.q_id, function(){`

Comment: this one works the same as the original. so it does highlight the border but it doesn't check the radio button